# Swift3 JSON Error - Cannot subscript value of type AnyObject

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swift2

Getting an error (Cannot subscript value of type 'AnyObject') in conversion from swift2 to swift3. The code is from monopoly game from github written in swift2.3

```
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: "properties", ofType: "json")
    var error: NSError?
    var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    do {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as AnyObject

        if let objects = json as? [AnyObject] {
            for obj in objects {
                var category = Category.special
                switch obj["Group"] as String! {    //error!
                    case "Brown": category = .brown
                    case "LightBlue": category = .lightBlue
                    case "Pink": category = .pink
                    case "Orange": category = .orange
                    case "Red": category = .red
                    case "Yellow": category = .yellow
                    case "Green": category = .green
                    case "Blue": category = .blue
                    default: category = .special
                }

                let name = obj["Name"] as String     //error!
                let price = obj["Price"] as Int      //error!
                let tile = obj["Position"] as Int    //error!
                var rent = 0
                if let r = obj["Rent"] as? Int {    //error! Ambiguous use of "subscript"
                    rent = r
                }

                let property = Property(name: name, category: category, price: price, tile: tile, rent: rent)
                game.tiles.append(property)
            }
    }
} catch {
print("error")
}
```

JSON:
[
  {
  "Name":"GO",
  "Position":1,
  "Price":0,
  "Rent":0,
  "Group":"GO"
  },
etc.]

Comment: You need to specify that `obj` is a Dictionary, so you can do `obj["MyKey"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your json as array of dictionary like `[[String:Any]]` instead of declaring it as `[AnyObject]`.

```
if let objects = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
     for obj in objects {
         var category = Category.special
         switch obj["Group"] as! String {
              case "Brown": category = .brown
              case "LightBlue": category = .lightBlue
              case "Pink": category = .pink
              case "Orange": category = .orange
              case "Red": category = .red
              case "Yellow": category = .yellow
              case "Green": category = .green
              case "Blue": category = .blue
              default: category = .special
         }
         //Add your other code
     }
}
```